# Including the decorator in the documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators

For this code:

```
@my_decorator(arg='abc')
def my_function(x, y):
    """ Return the sum of x and y"""
```

I'd like to automatically generate the documentation that shows not just the original (pre-decorator) function, but also the decorator itself. So something like this:

@my_decorator(arg='abc')
**my_function**(x, y)
  Return the sum of x and y

Preserving the signature of the original function is [not a problem](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) (using either `functools.wraps` or `decorator` library). But how can I get `sphinx` to include the decorator itself?

Given that sphinx `autofunction` looks at each function in runtime (after importing the module), the decorator was already applied, so it seems the information about the decorator is already irretrievably lost? Perhaps there's a plugin that can grab the decorator information from the static source file and combine it with whatever sphinx generated?

I have control over the decorator, if that helps.

Comment: A resource for you to search is the Sphinx issue tracker for [decorator](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=decorator). Sorry, I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: I wonder if https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1148 is the relevant issue (in which case it's a future enhancement to sphinx). (I'm the OP, btw, I'm just not sure if I understood the feature described in the issue correctly.)

Comment: Only one way to find out: modify the source code of Sphinx and test it. They are discussing this class: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/ca6a1edd2f97795eaba94e79e7ba34c40f83e2c7/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py#L1342